# jquery tools overlay problem after update to jquery 1.5.2

Tags: iframe, overlay, jquery-tools, jquery-1.5

This is just tricky.

In a Community are a few hyperlinks, which opens an overlay.
There is an iframe with the main content.

With jquery_1.4.3 all works fine. All overlays opens and are well positioned, doesn't matter if they are in iframe or not.

After update to jquery_1.5.2 nothing in iframe works fine.
The event "onBeforeLoad" is firing but event "onLoad" don't (tracked width alert).

I tried similar things, but nothing works.
Last thing I tried is what is described here
https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/issues/161

Is there anybody out there with an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Tested with a Jquery-tools 1.2.5 standalone ver against jQuery 1.5.2(jquery-tools not including jquery)

Overlay Completely failed to work in FF.